# How to get data from intermediate table Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

How to get data from third table through model?

I have model `Prototype`  and  `PrototypeField` model.

Where `Prototype` is:

```
id | name
```

Where `PrototypeField` is:

```
prototype_id | field_id
```

Also there is table `Field` that contains name of fields:

```
id | name
```

How to get names from table `Field` throught model 'Prototype' where `Prototype` relative with `PrototypeField` by:

```
Prototype.id = PrototypeField.prototype_id
```

So, `Prototype` can has one or many `PrototypeField`.

Comment: Have you setup the relationships in your models?

Comment: Can you explain how to set relationsship uin this case?

Answer (score 1):

Your prototype model should have a relationship inside it which specifies the fields it should be related to for example:

```
public function fields()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Fields'); // Change to location of fields model
}
```

Your fields model should also contain a relationship to specify which prototypes it relates to, for example:

```
public function prototypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Prototypes'); // Change to location of prototype model
}
```

Once you have set these up, you will then be able to select the fields which the prototype belongs to using the following:

```
Prototype::first()->fields; //This selects the first prototype and gets the associated fields.
```

The inverse of which would be:

```
Fields::first()->prototypes //This selects the first field and get associated prototypes.
```

You can find out lots of information by reading the documentation on Laravel models - https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships